Reimplementation of UI/UX ideas of commercial software in open source (MIT)
What are the legal implications of making an open source implementation (under MIT license) of commercial (closed source) software ideas in terms of UI/UX, logic of interface and general workflow, and design decisions related to that?
Background: There is single big commercial software in the field of engineering, but the area is very narrow and currently there is no open source alternative to that, there is also not even an alternative in commercial field (super specialized area).

If you are not already aware of it, worth reading the trash can icon lawsuit and related things. And I can tell you from some experience that if a big company thinks you will grab market share that legal fees to fight even copyright/patent/trademark/etc. can be a drop in the bucket for the big guys but bankrupt you out of business for the little guys (what does $1 million mean to a billion dollar corp? vs. what does it mean to you?) and they use that to their advantage. Beware.

You have to understand the difference between copyrights, patents and trademarks. Please read the quoted text below.
Copyrights protects only "original works of authorship fixed in a tangible medium of expression". It doesn't cover ideas, concepts, processes, facts and algorithms.
Ideas, concepts, processes and algorithms are protected by patents.
I assume you want to create an open source alternative a to a big commercial software, and this commercial software has a big UI/UX component.
Firstly, you should check if it (and other similar software) has any patents, and you should ensure that you do not infringe the patents. You do this by not implementing the ideas, concepts, processes and/or algorithms covered by the claims of those patents.
Please note that UI can be protected using design patents, as explained in Protecting Your UI with Design Patents by The Rapacke Law Group, citing examples of design patents by Facebook.
Secondly, you should avoid infringing the trademarks of that commercial software (and other similar software), by not using a logo, name and look that is too similar e.g. the "Mc" in "McChicken" of McDonalds, comes to mind. Even the UI design (e.g. color scheme) of your open source software should not look too similar to the commercial software.
Thirdly, you must not copy the source code, documentation, images or videos from the big commercial software, as those are protected by copyright law. However, the ideas, concepts, algorithms, UI/UX flows and/or processes can be copied from the commercial software, if they are not protected by patents.
Fourthly - consider fair use. You should avoid copying API definitions, specific names and specific terms as far as possible, if those names and terms are not common. For e.g. the term "wizard" is widely used, so it's ok for you to use it too. But, a term like "case" seems to be very specifically used by Salesforce, while most of its competitors use "ticket" (which is common) to describe the same concept. So, if you're copying Salesforce, you should use "ticket" rather than "case".
The reason for this is that those specific names, specific terms and API definitions fall into the gray area of potential fair use. Just because Java API's use by Google in Android was ruled to be fair use, it may not be the same for other cases. For you, it is a safer bet to tread on the safe side of fair use.
Fifthly - open source license selection. If you use the MIT license, anything developed by you can be taken by the commercial software company and used in their products, without giving any changes or improvements back to you. So, if my intention is to compete with the big commercial software, I would rather use a copyleft license like GPLv2+ or AGPLv3 or MPL2.
There is nothing wrong with having open source alternatives to big commercial software. LibreOffice as an alternative to Microsoft Office comes to mind and it's licensed under MPL2. An open source word processor called AbiWord is licensed under GPLv2+. I would think it's a bit risky to use the terms "office" and "word" for the name of the competing open source software alternative, but it has worked out so far for LibreOffice and AbiWord.
Let's take another example. Sparx Systems' Enterprise Architect is a very famous big UML2 commercial software, with a big UI/UX component. A surviving open source alternative is Papyrus, which is licensed under EPL2, a weak copyleft license.
From the U.S. Copyright Office FAQ page on Copyright In General:

What is copyright?
Copyright is a form of protection grounded in
the U.S. Constitution and granted by law for original works of
authorship fixed in a tangible medium of expression. Copyright covers
both published and unpublished works.
What does copyright protect?
Copyright, a form of intellectual property law,
protects original works of authorship including
literary, dramatic, musical, and artistic works, such as poetry,
novels, movies, songs, computer software, and architecture. Copyright
does not protect facts, ideas, systems, or methods of operation,
although it may protect the way these things are expressed. See
Circular 1, Copyright Basics, section "What Works Are Protected."
How is a copyright different from a patent or a trademark?
Copyright protects original works of authorship, while a patent
protects inventions or discoveries. Ideas and discoveries are not
protected by the copyright law, although the way in which they are
expressed may be. A trademark protects words, phrases, symbols, or
designs identifying the source of the goods or services of one party
and distinguishing them from those of others.
When is my work protected?
Your work is under copyright protection the
moment it is created and fixed in a tangible form that it is
perceptible either directly or with the aid of a machine or device.


So far so good, but this You do this by not implementing the ideas, concepts, processes and/or algorithms covered by the claims of those patents. is a bit too simplistic. The details matter - for a patent to be valid it (hopefully) needs to describe its invention in great detail, and actually have some relevant details. As long as a competing solution differs sufficiently in those details, it can absolutely implement the same "ideas, concepts, processes and algorithms". ... (cont.)

... So if OP wishes to provide the same functionality to the users of his software, he need to figure out what patents exist and what the relevant implementation details are that he needs to sufficiently change or avoid, to avoid patent claims.

It also depens on which laws you apply where and in which scope. Especially software patents are not recognized in some parts of the world.

It’s worth noting that being in the right won’t necessarily protect you from lawsuits so if you intend to do something highly visible you may also want to retain a lawyer with expertise in software intellectual property.

@PlasmaHH Most jurisdictions do not recognize pure software patents. However, all jurisdictions recognize software patents that have physical effects e.g. lossy audio compression algorithm that is optimized to not affect human voice and speech, while removing other irrelevant parts of the audio that's imperceptible to human hearing.

There's also "look and feel" copyright. This is what Apple sued Microsoft over when claiming that Windows copied the Macintosh GUI.

Libre Office derived from OpenOffice, which ultimately derived from Star Office, which was released in 1994 under this name. While Microsoft Office is 5 years older, I guess they missed the chance to protect the name "Office" back then. (The term also quite descriptive, so somewhat difficult to protect.)

@Barmar From my understanding, Apple failed in its lawsuit for copyright infringement based on "look and feel". However, based on Protecting Your UI with Design Patents, it's possible to protect UI using design patents.

@PlasmaHH Based on Protecting Your UI with Design Patents, it's possible to protect UI using design patents.

@ruben2020 AIUI it was never decided by a court, the two companies settled. But I think there have been other L&F copyright suits. And you're right that design patents can also be used, but it's more complicated to get a patent.
